# Extra window problem when generating .exe file with MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab, executable

usually i simply develop executable (.exe) files of my MATLAB codes by using this command:

```
mcc -m GUI.m
```

although there's no problem with the .exe creation, unfortunately when i opened the .exe, there's a black window (like command prompt) that is also opened, so two windows in total... the GUI figure and the prompt. how do i not have this prompt? is there any setting i can include in the mcc command as above?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add more info on what it is that you're trying to compile. Perhaps provide a minimal working example that reproduces the error so that we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: actually i have compiled a lot of .exes. and it is all the same. when i run all my compiled GUIs, they all open with a command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-e` instead of `-m` in the mcc command line. This will change how it's compiled (making it a GUI app instead of a console app), and suppress the command window. Requires Visual Studio. See `doc mcc` for details.