# compiling matlab GUI without matlab compiler

Tags: matlab, user-interface, exe

I was trying to create a stand-alone GUI in matlab for someone without matlab to use, and was wondering how I can go about doing it without buying the matlab compiler.

There was one post I found here:

[Extra window problem when generating .exe file with MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245399/extra-window-problem-when-generating-exe-file-with-matlab)

how do you go about setting up this? and if this still requires a compiler, what are my options? Some open sourced compilers perhaps?

Comment: *MATLAB Compiler (TM)* is not a real **compiler** like the name says, it just encrypts m-files which are then **interpreted** by *MATLAB Component Runtime (TM)* on the host machine

Comment: Step 1: Obtain $5000.
Step 2: Buy MATLAB Compiler.
Step 3: Compile m-files.

Comment: Thanks @Doresoom, I figured that much out...but I do believe that it was $500 instead of 5000.

Comment: @Henry: I'm pretty certain it's $5000, unless Mathworks is suddenly running a huge discount. I priced and purchased the compiler for my company last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compile MATLAB code, you need the [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/). Period.

You could try converting your MATLAB code to C or C++, then compiling that with a C or C++ compiler. However, the conversion would require [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/), another product you would need to purchase.

Your only real option if you are unwilling or unable to purchase the MATLAB Compiler is to request a [free product trial](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/tryit.html). The only limitation I know of is that it's not available to students, but there may be others.

Comment: will the MATLAB Compiler be effective with the figure production and the GUI?